# Log out when click on link

Tags: php, authentication, logout

I'm having trouble with my log in code for my website, the system allows for a user to log in and log out successfully however when the user is logged in and clicks on another webpage link, its signs them out. I want them to stay logged in on all pages until the user clicks log out themselves.

The loginform.php:

```
    <div id="contact">
       <form id="form" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
           Username: <input type="text" name="liusername" id="liusername">
           Password: <input type="password" name="lipassword" id="lipassword">
           <input type='submit' value='Login'   name="lisubmit">
       </form>
    </div>
```

PHP code on heading.php:

```
    <?php

if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] === true){

echo "You have signed in - <a href='loggedout.php'>Click here to log out</a>";

 } ELSE {
INCLUDE 'loginform.php';
 }

 if (isset($_POST['lisubmit'])){

$query = "SELECT user_id, user_password, user_username FROM users WHERE
        user_username = '".$_POST['liusername']."'";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        if ($row['user_password'] === $_POST['lipassword'] && $row['user_username'] === $_POST['liusername']){

            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['user_id'];
        }else{
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;
            $_SESSION['id'] = 0;
            INCLUDE 'loginform.php';

        }
}

   ?>
```

Index.php:

```
    if(empty($_SESSION['loggedin'])){$_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;
    }
```

Loggedout.php:

```
    <?php 

    session_start();

    $_SESSION= ARRAY();

    SESSION_DESTROY();

    HEADER('location: index.php');

    ?>
```

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html). Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and your errors will be revealed to you.

Comment: Do you have `session_start();` on all pages?

Comment: Are you calling `session_start` on each page before trying to access the sessions in `$_SESSION`?

Comment: I'm at university. This is the code we are required to use. I appreciate the update.

Comment: Yes, I am using session_start(); on all pages.

Comment: side comment:  I see this way too often.   what is the deal with college/university professors forcing students to use deprecated php code?  I understand if it's c, but in this case... wut?  I'm more inclined to believe the students are misunderstanding.   "forced?"  use the correct code!  it will serve you better.  If not PDO, use myqli prepared statements.  just as safe.

Comment: I get that, but I can only deal with what I have been taught and been asked to do.

Comment: post complete code of the page that when you visit, logs you out. I do not see any `session_start()` in your `index.php`